# Implementing VAE with initial parameter values

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I have been trying to implement a Variational Autoencoder. For VAE, we have a unit Gaussian prior and we infer the  posterior using the encoder which gives us mean and logvar.

I was wondering if there is a way to initialize the values of mean and logvar and then update them using the encoder part of VAE?

Comment: I don't understand the question - you have to initialize mean and logvar with *something*, so what's the problem with initializing it with something you know?

Comment: Problem is we are using the encoder to find the parameters of Variational posterior q(z |x). Unlike Variational inference algorithm where you  can intialize your sufficient statistics ( mean and variance), I'm not sure how to do that with Variational Auto-encoders